# Not getting screenLock notification on Swift 4 on mac

Tags: swift, macos, nsnotificationcenter, notificationcenter

For some reason I'm not getting the ScreenIsLocked and ScreenIsUnlocked notifications. I defined that the screen get locked 0 seconds after the screen saver starts and yet no log:

```
import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    @objc func screenLocked() {
        NSLog("yes")
    }

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to initialize your application

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(AppDelegate.screenLocked),
            name: Notification.Name("com.apple.screenIsLocked"),
            object: nil)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(AppDelegate.screenLocked),
            name: Notification.Name("com.apple.screenIsUnlocked"),
            object: nil)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(AppDelegate.screenLocked),
            name: Notification.Name("com.apple.screensaver.didstart"),
            object: nil)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(AppDelegate.screenLocked),
            name: Notification.Name("com.apple.screensaver.didstop"),
            object: nil)


    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application

    }


}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `NSDistributedNotificationCenter`

This is from a post by Kane Cheshire:

https://kanecheshire.com/blog/2014/10/13/351/

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {

    NSDistributedNotificationCenter *center = [NSDistributedNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [center addObserver:self
               selector:@selector(screenLocked)
                   name:@"com.apple.screenIsLocked"
                 object:nil];

    [center addObserver:self
               selector:@selector(screenUnlocked)
                   name:@"com.apple.screenIsUnlocked"
                 object:nil];
}
```

**In Swift:**

```
DistributedNotificationCenter.default().addObserver(self,
                                                    selector: #selector(screenLocked),
                                                    name: "com.apple.screenIsLocked",
                                                    object: nil)

DistributedNotificationCenter.default().addObserver(self,
                                                    selector: #selector(screenLocked),
                                                    name: "com.apple.screenIsUnlocked",
                                                    object: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's slightly different syntax now for the notification names.

```
        DistributedNotificationCenter.default().addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "com.apple.screenIsLocked"),
                                                            object: nil,
                                                            queue: .main) { [weak self] _ in
// Handle it
        }
        
        DistributedNotificationCenter.default().addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "com.apple.screenIsUnlocked"),
                                                            object: nil,
                                                            queue: .main) { [weak self] _ in
// Handle it
        }
```