# How to capture Lock/Unlock event time in macos/osx

Tags: python, macos

I am working on a project where, I need to capture Lock/Unlock and switch user event time in UTC time zone. It is solved for windows and Ubuntu, BUT I am stucked for MACOS/OSX. Any suggestion will be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

[NSWorkspace](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace) sends some notifications you could observe, e.g. for wake/sleep events. Screen lock/unlock can be catched via similar means. For this refer to the answers of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49914330/not-getting-screenlock-notification-on-swift-4-on-mac).

Comment: any example will be appreciable